# How to create and export complex symbology?

Tags: symbology, sld

I've got punctual geometries that I'd like to represent in a desktop and a web application, using complex symbology, like this : 
[image]

My idea is to use a symbology editor to create a SLD file that defines the symbols.
I used QGis to create the symbology and then tried saving it into a SLD file. The problem is that symbols are simplified and instead of the symbol I created, I get this one: 
[image]

Do you know about a SLD editor that supports complex symbology?

Do you have any other suggestion different from creating a SLD file?

Comment: any text editor can be used to create or modify SLD.

Comment: I want to create sld file using GUI.

Comment: uDIG or a text editor with a gui :-)